# Register here link button is not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am working in asp.net C#. I have created login page in which i have used validations to check if username or password is empty or not. Bu everytime i click on register here link it shows me to enter username or password. I am attaching code and image please help. Furthermore i have used link button for register here link.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyVoL.png)

Here is login.aspx.cs file code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI; 
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

namespace Dots
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        protected void Button1_ClickLogin(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new   SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();

            string checkUser = "Select count(*) from Registeration where UserName =  @username  and Password = @pass";
            SqlCommand sq = new SqlCommand(checkUser, conn);
            sq.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBoxUserName.Text);
            sq.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", TextBoxPassword.Text);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sq);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username and Password')</script>");
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Response.Redirect("Registeration.aspx");

        }

    }
}
```

Here is my aspx code.

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Dots.Login" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Styles/StyleSheet1.css" />
   <br /><br />
    <center>
    <div class="Login">
        <br />
        <div class="Login_Form">
            <h1>Secure Login</h1>
            <div class="Table">

                <table style="width: 100%; height: 161px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-size: medium; width: 127px"><strong style="text-align: right">UserName</strong></td>
                        <td style="width: 176px">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxUserName" runat="server" Width="180px" CssClass="Login_un" Height="22px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter Username" ControlToValidate="TextBoxUserName" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 127px"><strong>Password</strong></td>
                        <td style="width: 176px">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxPassword" runat="server" Width="180px" CssClass="Login_un" TextMode="Password" Height="22px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter Password" ControlToValidate="TextBoxPassword" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 127px">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="width: 176px">
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_ClickLogin" CssClass="Login_btn" Text="Button" />
                        </td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 127px; height: 23px;"></td>
                        <td style="width: 176px; height: 23px;">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">New User? Register Here</asp:LinkButton>
                        </td>
                        <td style="height: 23px"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    </center>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Probably you need to add the APSX markup.

Comment: Share your `.aspx `code as well.

Comment: I have added .aspx code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this code :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">New User? Register Here</asp:LinkButton>
```

to :

```
<a href="Registeration.aspx">New User? Register Here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" >New User? Register Here</asp:LinkButton>
```

to

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" ValidateRequestMode="Disabled">New User? Register Here</asp:LinkButton>
```

**Here is some additional feedback.**

I would suggesting surrounding with a `try/catch/finally` so if you redirect you close the connection to the Database rather than leaving it open if you redirect. It is just good practice.

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString);
        try {
            conn.Open();
            string checkUser = "Select count(*) from Registeration where UserName =  @username  and Password = @pass";
            SqlCommand sq = new SqlCommand(checkUser, conn);
            sq.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBoxUserName.Text);
            sq.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", TextBoxPassword.Text);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sq);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
                Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
            } else {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username and Password')</script>");
            }
        } finally {
            conn.Close();
        }
```